# How to start contributing to Unity?

Tags: unity, development

I just forked the source code of Unity. I am new to contributing to the project.

Do unity developers use any specific IDE?

I am asking this because I am confused about where to start and how exactly do I check a change after I do it?

Should I recompile entire natty? If so, then how?

I know I am asking a lot of questions, but it would be really helpful if someone could write some kind of beginner friendly introduction to unity development.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [getting involved](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/) page on unity.ubuntu.com has an initial set of instructions to get started.

It looks like you've already branched the code. You can just edit it with whatever editor you prefer (the unity folks don't have a specific IDE, it's just personal preference). After you've made the change you want you can do a `bzr commit` and then you need to build Unity to test it:

- [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

You don't have to follow the part of the instructions where you pull unity from Launchpad, you've already done that.

After you've fixed what you want you can submit the branch to Launchpad if you want the Unity folks to integrate it.

We have a page full of [bitesize bugs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Bitesize) for people who are just getting started if they want to tackle something small to get used to the codebase.

- [IRC Logs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/devweek1103/HelpingWithUnity) from a tutorial session.
- [How to contact](http://unity.ubuntu.com/contact-us/) the Unity team.

If you have *specific* questions about parts of the unity code just ask them as new questions and tag them with [unity](/questions/tagged/unity) and Unity developers will look at them, it will be useful to start building up a bunch of questions and answers about the Unity codebase!

Answer (score 0):

You can find several ways of getting involved in Unity's development here: http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/

You don't need a VM, you can run Unity from your development directory without replacing your system files.  And of course you can join #ubuntu-unity on freenode to talk to the other developers.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I have built nux but building unity returns an error.  It says that no target was specified by the make file.  I followed their steps exactly(or im pretty sure at least).  Does making it require a target when i call the function?

Comment: It didn't the last time I built it, which I'll admit was a while ago.  Try joining #ubuntu-unity on freenode and asking them for help.

Comment: Good Idea.  I will try that and ask them.