# How can I move the Dash button from the Unity launcher to the top panel?

Tags: unity, launcher, configuration, unity-dash

In Ubuntu 11.10 the Unity Dash button moved from top-left corner to the launcher. How can I restore the Dash button to the top-corner, as pictured below

[image: Image of desired affect]

Comment: This sounds like something that would require modifying Unity's source and recompiling it. I wouldn't know the exact steps, however.

Comment: The provided [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/843373) was marked as invalid (since it wasn't really even a bug in the first place) and converted into a [Launchpad question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+question/170417).

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible in Unity without modifying Unity's source and recompiling it.

- [How to start contributing to Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29251/how-to-start-contributing-to-unity)
- [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

Answer (score -1):

Open `dconf-editor`. Go to com → unity-2d → panel. Then insert "**homebutton**" inside other applets.