# I want to learn how to help or contribute to Unity

Tags: unity, development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start contributing to Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29251/how-to-start-contributing-to-unity)

I am a college student studying computer science and would one day like to work on operating systems.  The part of ubuntu that really interests me is Unity and I would like to study it and possibly contribute to it.

I was reading the wiki pages about it and it was saying to get a copy of all the required components and then start hacking.  Would it be wise to do this in a virtual machine with ubuntu on it?  Do you have any advice on a good place to start?  Do you know of any common pitfalls?  Should I also post in the irc for this?

Thanks