# How to resize the top panel in Unity?

Tags: unity, panel

I want to resize (increase size) the Ubuntu 11.10 top taskbar, no the unity launcher, i've searched it on google, but i'm not encountered any solution.

I need it only for customize my Ubuntu 11.10 installation, for make it more aestetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### For 11.10:

Unfortunately this part of Unity is not customizable in Ubuntu 11.10, it is possible by [editing the source](https://askubuntu.com/a/123062/235) in 12.04.

Answer (score 12):

#### For 12.04:

Yes, now you can.

Unfortunately you can't do it by options or theming (even if adding a more CCSM option would be trivial), but you can easily change the `plugins/unityshell/PanelStyle.cpp` (in 12.04) or `panel/PanelStyle.cpp` (in later versions) `panel_height` property, setting it to a value you want. See:

[image: Unity with panel height set to 44px]

The only thing that doesn't "match" that value, is the icon size. However you can increase their size easily by editing the value defined in `PanelIndicatorEntryView::MakePixbuf` (currently hardcoded to 22px) and then rebuild Unity:

- [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

Comment: And after one has committed the changes to the source code, one has to build Unity from the source :)

Comment: *"but you can easily change the plugins/unityshell/PanelStyle.cpp's panel_height property"* Do you mind explaing how it can be done?
Thank you.

Comment: @David, follow the instructions to build unity linked above, then before compiling and installing, just edit the file panel/PanelStyle.cpp so that the panel_height hardcoded value matches your wishes

Comment: @Treviño Where is `PanelIndicatorEntryView::MakePixbuf` located in 13.10? I can not change the icon size in ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to shrink it. Try this:

1) Go into the system settings (unity-control-center.)
2) Go to Displays
3) Mess around with scale.

Answer (score -1):

Hey Guys I think I found a way to reduce the icon size in the top panel.I am using ubuntu 13.10 but am pretty sure it should work for the previous versions too.

[image]

First install kde system settings by adding

```
sudo apt-get install systemsettings
```

Open the kde system setting and navigate to th Icons tab

At this point you have the option to tweak the icons size on the panels so you select advance and then choose panel.

Now you can tweak the icon size of the indicators and system apps on the panels.

[image]

[image]