# Can I resize Unity Panel height in 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resize the top panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88031/how-to-resize-the-top-panel-in-unity)

I want to know if there's a new possibility to adjust Unity top panel in **12.04.**

Since BUG https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/928544 seems to be fixed, where can we find the constant : `panel_height` and assign it a new value?

One can reduce default font size and icons size but no way for the to panel. It's not in the CSS but I suspect it to be hard coded in unityshell.

Possible duplicate: [How to resize the top panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88031/how-to-resize-the-top-panel-in-unity)