# How to change top panel size?

Tags: 16.04, panel

How can resize top panel on ubuntu 16.04 ?

I searched but the only thing i [found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88031/how-to-resize-the-top-panel-in-unity) no longer works.

Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible since the introduction of Unity in Ubuntu.

Resizing the top panel is a Gnome feature and not part of Unity. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40415/how-do-i-resize-gnome-shell-top-bar

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Settings → Display
- Turn on the [fractional scaling]
- Finally change [scale]

It is for Ubuntu 19 and 20 but if you use Unity like me, maybe the setting is same.

Comment: Were there meant to be links/screenshots in your answer, that have got lost? I only ask as there are `[` and `]` but they aren't linked to anything.