# Can I modify unity keyboard shortcut overlay?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

As per this bug [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/960960/comments/3), shortcuts for the keyboard shortcuts overlay get pulled dynamically from user's settings.
Is it possible to change which shortcuts are included (i.e. show more of them - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> minimizes window on my computer but it is not included)?

Comment: There is an open (at the time of writing) bug that suggests making the overlay modifiable. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1591109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the shortcuts that show in the keyboard shortcut overlay are hardcoded. If you want to change or modify what shows up, you need to compile Unity from source.

- [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

In the Unity source, go to Plugins → UnityShell → src → unityshell.cpp and modify them as you wish and then build Unity from source.

My keyboard shortcut overlay modification to include the shortcut for Video lens:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could patch unity as per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/937334  or more specifically: https://launchpadlibrarian.net/94791764/videolensshortcut.diff

Comment: That was my patch yeah. But, it needs to be refreshed since there were some other changes to that particular file. I assume you now know how to edit the overlay. :)

Comment: Yeah, I will not be recompiling Unity because of this, so I instead fill a bug about it in Launchpad, let's see if it gets rejected right away or not. https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/995086