# Are the default keyboard shortcuts changeable and does the shortcut help change accordingly

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, keyboard

Are the keyboard shortcuts shown in the image changeable with a GUI or Terminal way and does the Keyboard Shortcut help (The one that appears when you hold the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> hey) show the updated keyboard changes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts are changeable but the shortcut keys showing in the keyboard shortcut overlay are not dynamic. Meaning that if you change the shortcuts, the change will not be reflected in the overlay.

All of the keyboard shortcuts are currently hardcoded in Unity and any change in the default set of keyboard shortcuts will then have to be updated in the overlay.

If I am not wrong, you can modify the shortcut overlay by editing the source file

```
plugins/unityshell/src/unityshell.cpp
```

and then manually compiling Unity.

- [Can I modify unity keyboard shortcut overlay?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126834/can-i-modify-unity-keyboard-shortcut-overlay)