# desktop-name ("Ubuntu Desktop")

Tags: 12.04

I see someone asked how to change in unity top left corner label (ubuntu desktop) there is an answer but it is no very clear, can someone explain it with more details, 
i am pasting  the  answer that was posted but i need more directions,
thanks

You would likely need to build the unity or unity-2d source. Currently in unity-5.12 would be found in `/plugins/unityshell/src/PanelMenuView.cpp`, line **78**

```
 _desktop_name(_("Ubuntu Desktop"))
```

In unity-2d, unity-2d 5.12, `/panel/applets/appname/appnameapplet.cpp` line **369**

```
d->m_label->setText(u2dTr("Ubuntu Desktop"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the desktop name on the Unity panel?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140742/how-do-i-change-the-desktop-name-on-the-unity-panel)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't understand this, then I don't recommend doing it.
What it's saying is that you would need to get the source code and you would have to have programming knowledge and alter the text in there. After which you would have to compile it and install.
It is tedious and not for the beginner

Comment: Tedious and (for me at least) never seems to work...