# Hide or change 'Ubuntu Desktop' on upper bar

Tags: 12.04, appmenu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the desktop name on the Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140742/how-do-i-change-the-desktop-name-on-the-unity-panel)

How do i hide or change the wording on the top bar in Ubuntu 12.04?

I'd like to alter it from 'Ubuntu desktop' to 'Mac OS X' but i am unsure of how to do this. There was a thread explaining this a while ago but i didn't understand the process completely meaning i haven't been able to give it a go.

Hope you can help, UbuntuRob.