# Change "Ubuntu Desktop" on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: appearance, icon-themes

I would like to ask if I can change the "ubuntu desktop" text with a single ubuntu (or any other) icon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has already been answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140742/how-do-i-change-the-desktop-name-on-the-unity-panel).

Comment: Partially... They say how you can replace text message with another text message. However, they do not say anything about how to replace the text with an icon

Comment: You could use a unicode font icon.