# Where do I get the source code to customize Unity?

Tags: unity, customization, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

So one of the main reasons I migrated to Ubuntu 12.04 from Windows 7 was to be able to have more control over my system due to the flexibility and customizability of a Linux operating system. However, with Ubuntu I do not feel as if I am as in control as I can be. What I mean to say is, where are the source codes and everything for all of this that I can edit on my machine. For example, suppose I want to position my dock on the left to be on the right without wanting to install any new software. I simply want to see the GUI files and reposition it myself. How can I do that, if that's even possible?

Thank You!