# How to build Compiz from source?

Tags: compiz, compiling, install-from-source

Similarly to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source) question made for Unity, I would like to know what is the correct procedure to build the latest development release of [Compiz](https://code.launchpad.net/compiz) from source.

In particular, it would be useful to know if it's possible to install it avoiding the risk of breaking the one from the repositories (maybe using checkinstall, or installing it in a different location?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the same question and the related answer on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/compiz/+question/203490)

Specifically:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/staging
make install

And then in a VT (Ctrl+Alt+F1):
cd ~/staging
env DISPLAY=:0 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib ./bin/compiz --replace composite opengl move resize decor compiztoolbox mousepoll wall expo animation switcher
```

That way you're not affecting your system installation. Everything runs from ~/staging.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the steps specified in the linked Launchpad answer.

Comment: you should accept your answer to this question falls out of the 'Unanswered Questions' list.

Comment: I used above instructions to build and run Compiz 0.9.10.0 on UBuntu 12.04 LTS. It works but when I change something in xml configuation files which are located in **./share/compiz** it doesn't affect plugins. The same thing works for default Compiz (version 0.9.7.12 for UBuntu 12.04) - xml files are located in **/usr/share/compiz** How to achieve that for Compiz which is built from a source ?