# What Language is unity written in?

Tags: unity, gnome, programming, source-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

What Language is Unity written in? Also, where can i get its source code?

I have an idea for a windowing enviroment or shell (dont know what to call it). What i want to do is teach myself to create it.

i like some of several ideas i have seen, but i want to redo all of them, also the concept of how a desktop works.

I figured learning the language Unity is written in, and studying Unity and Gnomes code would be a good start.

i am on Ubuntu 12.04
acer aspire 5920
3 gb ram
160 gb hard drive

Answer (score 3):

Unity is developed using C, C++ and Vala. [This Link](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/) will provide all information about Unity Development. Check out
 [Gnome Developer Center](http://developer.gnome.org/) for Gnome Development. You will get tutorials for Gnome development and platform related information.

Answer (score 2):

Unity is written mostly in C++. It's source code can be found in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/unity). To get the code you need Bazaar. This which can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
```

Then to create a branch of the code you would execute

```
bzr branch lp:unity trunk
```

This creates the directory `trunk` with the Unity source code. If you just want to look at the code, you're done. If you want to build it you will need to install some dependent libraries. This is most likely just `Nux` but can, depending on your setup, have more requirements.

More information about developing Unity can be found on the [Unity development page](http://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/). A more detailed explanation of building the current Unity from source can also be found with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/28472/55238)