# Where can I get Unity source

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source)

I would like to test Unity in a Funtoo environment. Therefore I need to manually install it from source.

Is there a git I can download from ? Thank's in advance.