# Version 12.04 and Unity upgrade

Tags: unity, updates

When Unity updates, is it possible to install it to 12.04? I've seen some howto's on this, but they don't seem to work for me. For instance, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/ppa` doesn't seem to work at Noobslab.

So I assume that Unity versions are tied closely to the distro and updating Unity without updating Ubuntu is not recommended? Is there a link to the latest PPA for Unity? I don't know how those PPA sites work. I'm new here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There will not be an official backport, but you can [build unity from source](http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source).

[Here is a good link with some more information.](http://launchpad.net/~benkai/+archive/precise-unity-backport)