# How to re-install Unity from PPA

Tags: 12.04, unity, ppa

I found some PPA that is patching Unity. (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/789979
)

I want to re-install unity from this PPA.

How can I do?

**EDIT**: The accepted answer below is to how to build your own version of Unity.. please carefully read all comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear there is a PPA for that code. You can either wait for the fix to be released, update your version of Ubuntu, or build from source.

From the README included in the code / patch

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ikarosdev/unity/5.0_unity-revamped/files

> • Installation
>
> Please see INSTALL or http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/InstallationGuideFromSource

The link then re-directs to an answer here:

[How do I build Unity from source?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source/28472#28472)

NOTE: If you build from source support will be limited, at best.

Comment: So, You think `http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~iaz/unity/menubar-lp789979/changes/2384?start_revid=2384` is not built yet? As I've this `http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/unity/ubuntu` added as a PPA in my sources. Sorry, I am very new to Launchpad.

Comment: There are no packages anywhere in that tree (if you look in the sub directories).

Comment: I found packages here : http://ppa.launchpad.net/iaz/unity/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unity/ If the do not install with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` , post any error messages.

Comment: BTW, the links you put above is very cool, I gonna clone the repo on my machine, do the change and then build/install the new unity locally.

Comment: I've tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` many times before, but cannot see the final result as stated in the above issue link (in my question). Can you help me make sure that I've the Unity version of this PPA?

Comment: If you did not get any error messages, log out and back in, or perhaps reboot (although it is unlikely you need to reboot) and see in your bug is fixed. To check your version of Unity, type `unity --version`.

Comment: I did build it from source, but I noticed that I need the exact version compatible with my system (in terms of gcc and other build tools), so it is very better to know the version on my system, and clone the exact version from lp.