# Are Ubuntu and/or Unity FOSS?

Tags: license

As the title states,

Are Ubuntu and/or Unity open source software?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source

Comment: That answered my question. It didn't come up as an option when I created the question title.

Comment: No, that doesn't answer your question. Open Source software is not necessarily free (as in beer), and free software is not necessarily free (as in freedom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes both Ubuntu and Unity are open source softwares.

https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29