# How to apply a fix to a bug?

Tags: unity, 15.04, launcher, patch

I have reported a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1450991) a few months ago. And now seems that bug has been fixed as its status shows "fix committed". And also sounds that it is going to be released in the next version of Ubuntu, i.e. 15.10.

Is it possible for me to apply this fix right now on my 15.04? If so, how? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to compile Unity yourself (with dependencies) if there is no PPA for this (I dont think there is). For a simple bug like this, I don't think that this is worth the hassle.

If you are curious about how to compile it yourself, please refer to this [Ask Ubuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source).

Comment: Is there other ways other than compiling by myself?

Comment: You could try on of the PPAs maintained by unity-team: https://launchpad.net/~unity-team. But I would not recommend it, unless you know what you are doing.