# Recompiling unity from source

Tags: unity, apt, compiling

For some reason I have to modify some files on the source of unity. To get the source and its dependencies I had issued `apt-get build-dep unity` and `apt-get source unity`. To test whether the source compiles without any modifications or even any additional configuration, I created a `build` directory on the source, issued `cmake ..` then `make`. It always fails on `make` with this line

```
unity-7.2.5+14.04.20150603/unity-shared/pch/unity-shared_pch.hh:30:21: fatal error: Nux/Nux.h: No such file or directory
```

even though `libnux-4.0-dev` is installed.
Trying with the additional configuration found at `debian/rules` by the `cmake_base_options` variable in cmake doesn't make a difference either.

What did go wrong?

My system is on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: try installing libnux-4.0-dev  `sudo apt-get install libnux-4.0-dev `

Comment: I've tried to install that but apt stated it was already installed, and build still fails for the same reason.

Comment: ok then, try locating Nux.h either with `find` or `locate`. perhaps it was installed in an unexpected place.

Comment: it is installed at `/usr/include/Nux-4.0/Nux/Nux.h`, nothing weird there.

Comment: what Unity version are you trying to build? Im downloading it, and it says version 7.3 in version 7.3, the nux dependency seems to be for compiz. can you compile without compiz?  it also says nux-4.0>=4.0.5 is that the nux version you have?

Comment: I'm sure it's not about the dependency, because I am using the unity version that came with 14.04 which is I think 7.2.

Comment: try this if you havent already http://askubuntu.com/questions/28470/how-do-i-build-unity-from-source